# prevent from checking errors on rerender a section

Tags: rerender, error

When I rerender a pageBlockSection and a field is required but not filled, then an error is displayed on page. I don't want these errors untill I click on save button. So, how to prevent the checking for errors on page on rerender.

Answer (score 3):

**apex:actionRegion**

You can define a [`<apex:actionRegion>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm) around your actionSupport call, this way, only the part of the page inside your actionRegion is submitted to the controller. And only the validations to those fields will be done.

If you not include the field that is required but not filled in, you won't get the error message.

Keep in mind, if you use this, and you rerender a section of the page that is not included in your actionRegion, all the data in that section will be put on blank. Because when you use this, only a part of the data is submitted to the controller/extension, the controlling object is rebuild and all the missing fields are put on blank , when the controller/extension sends the object back to the page, and rerenders a section of the page where data can be field in, but wasn't included in the actionRegion, the blank data from the returning object will overwrite the current data in those fields. (if that makes sense :))

**immediate="true"**

On some components you also have the "immediate" attribute (for example [`<apex:commandButton>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm)), when you set this to true, all validations on the page will be skipped and the action in the controller will be executed, note that this is probably not for this usecase, you would use this for example when creating your own "Cancel" action, all validation is skipped, and cancel is executed.